# SASS solution to using the same base64 image in different CSS files?

Tags: base64, sass

Im using SASS and base64 encoded images. Im reusing the same background image im multiple places and ideally I like to keep the code in separate files.

So this would be my SASS code if I wasnt using base64 images:

```
$background-image: url(image-file.jpg);

.div1 {
    background-image: $background-image;
}

//This is in a seperate file
.div2 {
    background-image: $background-image;
}
```

However if I now replace the image url with a base64 image then it looks like the following. The issue is that the base64 encoded string is repeated which will increase the filesize unnecessarily.

```
$background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk);      

.div1 {
    background-image: $background-image;
}
//This is in a seperate file
.div2 {
    background-image: $background-image;
}
```

So is there a way to keep my code nice and organised in separate files, and use base64 images, and not repeate the base64 string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `@extend`.

```
%my-bg {
    background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk);
}

.div1 {
    @extend %my-bg;
}

//This is in a seperate file
.div2 {
    @extend %my-bg;
}
```

Output:

```
.div1, .div2 {
  background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk);
}
```

It's not necessary to split off the background image like that (ie. you chould just `@extend .div;` instead), but I assume `.div1` will have additional styles that are different from `.div2` and shouldn't be shared.